# Table not in same order mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel, csv

I loaded a csv file into mySQL using the load data local infile command. When I view the table, the rows are in different order than the csv file. Is there a way to have them be in the same order.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY column_name` to order a queries result

Comment: SQL represents *unordered* sets.  If you wish to order the results in the table, you need to specify what column to order by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a relational database tables do not have any inherent "order". If you want to view rows in a particular order than you should use the `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` statement. If you're viewing the data through some UI then it's up to the UI to provide that functionality (or not).

Answer (score 3):

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no ordering.  There is a trick, however.  I am assuming that you are using `load data infile`.  Define your table to have an auto-incremented identity column:

```
create table . . . (
    tableId int auto_increment primary key,
    . . .
);
```

Then, when you load the data from the file into the table, you can list all the fields *except for `tableId`* (or the fields that are appropriate).  And explicitly use `set testId = NULL`.

Then you can access the table using:

```
select t.*
from t t
order by tableId;
```

Unfortunately, I've never found documentation that this is *guaranteed* to increment the ids in insertion order.  I do believe it works in practice, though.

Comment: I would like to have the mySQL in the same order as the Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: @Crt . . . I am assuming you are using `load data infile`.  If not, just add a column to the spreadsheet with the explicit ordering and remember to include that in the `order by` clause when you fetch the data.